# How can I arrange the list according to similar item in certain location

Tags: python, list

I wanted to arrange the "test" list items for the second part = "1_1man:Army" which have similar words and then arrange it so that the values after "1_1man:Army" which is the values for "stack" and "testing" to be next to each other in a new column.

Input :

```
test = [[[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'stack'], 
    [[0.45, '3_3man::army'], 'flow'], 
    [[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'testing'], 
    [[0.52, '2_2man:army'], 'expert']]
```

code:

```
for x in test:
print(x[0][1])
```

Expected output:

print(test)

```
test = [[[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'stack', 'testing'], 
        [[0.45, '3_3man::army'], 'flow'], 
        [[0.52, '2_2man:army'], 'expert']]
```

Could anyone assist me please. If possible to arrange it in ascending order according to the integer value (0.45,0.52)

Sort output :

```
test = [[[0.45, '3_3man::army'], 'flow'],
[[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'stack', 'testing'], 
[[0.52, '2_2man:army'], 'expert']]
```

Updated:

How can I load it if I want to use the example shown by Rahul at below?

my text file is like this

```
[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'stack'] 
[0.45, '3_3man::army'], 'flow']
[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'testing'] 
[0.52, '2_2man:army'], 'expert']
```

how to load it?

Comment: It is a list in a list. If you use test[0] you get [[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'stack', 'testing'], if you use test[0][0] you get the 0.52

Comment: Yea, I re-edited my question. I made a mistake and renew it

Comment: Could you help me with this?

Comment: So first step, you want to do a groupby operation, and second step, you want to do a sorting.

Comment: Yes, i wanted to group it then sort it. I edited my sort part too.

Comment: import operator, test=sorted(test, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

Comment: Hi sir, can you tell me how to load from the text into the 2nd part of the list. "1_1man:army"?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `groupby`,

```
In [41]: from itertools import groupby
In [42]: for g,val in groupby(sorted(test,key=lambda x:x[0][1]),key=lambda x:x[0][1]):
    ...:     g_values = list(val)
    ...:     keys = [i[1] for i in g_values]
    ...:     print list([g_values[0][0]] + keys)
    ...:     
    ...:     
[[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'stack', 'testing']
[[0.52, '2_2man:army'], 'expert']
[[0.45, '3_3man::army'], 'flow']
```

`sorted` is important here, For `groupby` it will group with adjusting elements only. And lambda function used to identify the grouping key.

**Edit 1**

As per the modification made in your question. If you need to sort based on the float value.

```
In [60]: result = []
In [58]: for g,val in groupby(sorted(test,key=lambda x:x[0][1]),key=lambda x:x[0][1]):
    ...:     g_values = list(val)
    ...:     keys = [i[1] for i in g_values]
    ...:     result.append(list([g_values[0][0]] + keys))
    ...:     

In [60]: sorted(result,key=lambda x:x[0][0])
Out[60]: 
[[[0.45, '3_3man::army'], 'flow'],
 [[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'stack', 'testing'],
 [[0.52, '2_2man:army'], 'expert']]
```

**Edit 2**

If you are reading from a file.

```
In [83]: from ast import literal_eval

In [84]: fp = open('file_name.txt')

In [85]: test = [literal_eval(i) for i in fp.readlines()]
```

Final Solution will be like this.

```
from ast import literal_eval
fp = open('file_name.txt')
test = [literal_eval(i) for i in fp.readlines()]
result = []
for g,val in groupby(sorted(test,key=lambda x:x[0][1]),key=lambda x:x[0][1]):
    g_values = list(val)
    keys = [i[1] for i in g_values]
    result.append(list([g_values[0][0]] + keys))
print(sorted(result,key=lambda x:x[0][0]))
```

Comment: Sir, what about if i need to load from text file? example my text file is like this 

[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'stack']
[0.45, '3_3man::army'], 'flow']
[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'testing']
[0.52, '2_2man:army'], 'expert']

Comment: Thank you sir but can I ask how to load the text file? I updated my question at most bottom part

Comment: Could you help me with that sir?

Comment: sir, I could not sort it using your solution. Btw, could you please assist me in the load file too

Comment: Sorry for my late response. The value somehow sorted according to the [0][1] and not [0][0] numerical values. I used the solution you gave but it sorted differently.

Comment: @JJson It's sorting according to [0][0]. I don't know how it's sorted with [0][1] for you. Please use my last code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to create a dictionary of lists. Then use a list comprehension to link keys with with values in a list of lists. The solution has O(n) complexity as, unlike `itertools.groupby`, it does not require sorting beforehand.

```
test = [[[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'stack'], 
        [[0.45, '3_3man::army'], 'flow'], 
        [[0.52, '1_1man::army'], 'testing'], 
        [[0.52, '2_2man:army'], 'expert']]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in test:
    d[tuple(key)].append(value)

res = [[k]+v for *k, v in d.items()]
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

[[[(0.52, '1_1man::army')], 'stack', 'testing'],
 [[(0.45, '3_3man::army')], 'flow'],
 [[(0.52, '2_2man:army')], 'expert']]
```