# How to load text file in python?

Tags: python, text

I have a text file like this:

```
[0.52, '1_1man::army'], stack 
[0.45, '3_3man::army'], flow
[0.52, '1_1man::army'], testing 
[0.52, '2_2man:army'], expert
```

How can I load into the file and print all the values for

```
'1_1man::army', '3_3man::army', '1_1man::army' and '2_2man:army'
```

My code:

```
text = open("text.txt", "r").readlines()
print(text[1])
```

Then to implement the solutions some good people have shared. I cant use their codes since the file I have now is different from the one I posted(I wish to try out this new example).

[How can I arrange the list according to similar item in certain location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035779/how-can-i-arrange-the-list-according-to-similar-item-in-certain-location/52037806#52037806)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have the code so I will add it in right now

Comment: might try the search option. this is a pretty basic question which has probably been asked many times before.

Comment: I tried to search for it too but unfortunately nothing with the similar format as my file.

Comment: Side-note: Are all those far right brackets really unmatched by left brackets? That's... odd. If there were properly matched, line by line parsing with `json` would work. Otherwise, your format looks custom to the point of lunacy; you'd likely have to write any parser from scratch.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistakes, I have edited it. I was trying to try another example by adding something and forgot to change it to the original version.

Answer (score 5):

If that format is rigid throughout the file. You could simply use `split()` to extract those values in between quotes

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print (line.split("'")[1])
```

`line.split("'")` slices the string up whenever it sees a `'`. In your case, every line would be sliced into a list of 3 elements:

```
[0.52, 
1_1man::army
], stack
```

You want the middle one, which has index `[1]`. So `line.split("'")[1]` gives you exactly that.

Comment: Thank you so much and I am currently trying to see whether I could use this to implement the codes I received from previous post

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach to this would to make a json file instead. Python was a good built in json reading library. This is what the json would look like:

```
{
    "1_1man::army": "stack",
    "3_3man::army": "flow",
    "1_1man::army": "testing",
    "2_2man::army": "expert",
}
```

You would enter this and change the file extension from .txt to .json. You can read it like this:

```
import json

with open("YourText/JsonFileHere.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

// Get first 1_1man::army value
data[0]["1_1man::army"]

// Get 3_3man::army value
data["3_3man::army"]

// Get second 1_1man::army value
data["1_1man::army"]

// Get 1_1man::army value
data[1]["1_1man::army"]

// in order to add things to the json do this:
data["What you want the new key to be called"] = "What the value is"
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This text file is actually lead to another example I would like to try and I had asked about it on another topic. If I were to change it to json file then it will be rejecting my whole intention of trying it out with text file. This is my previous topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035779/how-can-i-arrange-the-list-according-to-similar-item-in-certain-location/52037806#52037806

Comment: You should now be able to add stuff to the .json file.